# Get a callback when a deeply nested property changes, with a WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**What I'm talking about**

On a WPF form, I can create a simple WPF binding for a deeply nested object:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Very/Deeply/Nested/Object}"></TextBox>
```

TextBox1 will update automatically when any of the properties in the hierarchy changes. So, for example, if the property 'Deeply' of the object 'Very' changes, WPF will unsubscribe from the previous item, and subscribe to the new hierarchy. Eventually the Text property will be updated.

**What I want to do**

On the C# side, I need to get callbacks when 'Object' changes. However, I **don't need to display** Object in any WPF control. Also, I **don't want to subscribe/unsubscribe manually to the whole hierarchy**, How can use the subscription mechanism of WPF in C# to get a callback from a deeply nested object property?

**A bad solution I found**

I could make TextBox1 invisible (since I don't actually need to display that information), and subscribe to it's TextChanged event. It's very simple, it would probably work, but it really looks like a bad approach...

**Another way to see this question**

Can you use the binding mechanism on something else than a control property? IDK, could I create some kind of non-static and constantly subscribed resource? That resource would use the specified binding, and I could subscribe to a single 'changed' event form that resource.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If your 'Nested' is INotifyPropertyChanged implemented you can subscribe to its PropertyChanged event in viewmodel. You will get notification when ever thr is change in any proprty including Object

Comment: But then you need to subscribe to the whole hierarchy to eventually get to the last one, and it is what I want to avoid.